# Make Checkbutton togglable graphs in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, plot

I'm attempting to embed graphs into my tkinter gui using FigureCanvasTkAgg but am having some difficulty. I tried making a function to have the graphs appear when the checkbutton is activated by having the onvalue call the function and pass in a subplot number so that way when the checkbuttons were activated, they would appear in the proper order. The aforementioned code is listed below:

```
def graphs(num):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    sensor_graph = f.add_subplot(num)
    sensor_graph.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])

    canvas = FigureCancasTkAgg(f)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

The data for the graph that's in there was just dummy data to see if it was working or not, which is how I know it doesn't work. The checkbutton call looks akin to:

```
sensor_1 = ttk.Checkbutton(sensor_frame, text = sensor_list[0] + ' [%s]' % sensor_units[0], onvalue =lambda: graphs[811], offvalue = 'Pizza', variable=clap1)
```

When I call this function with the present code, this is what I get:
[Before activating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okbEh.jpg),
[after activating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMFAW.jpg)

Along with this, I'm trying to add a scrollbar to the canvas such that instead of the window expanding to fit the subplots, instead, I can just scroll through the different graphs. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A function in python is called with round parantheses, not with square brackets

Comment: You should use the callback assigned to `command` option to toggle the graph instead of `onvalue=lambda: ...`.

Comment: Thank you both, by applying both your remedies (I can't believe I missed that bracket oversight) I was able to fix that problem but unfortunately it has lead to another: Now, only one subplot will appear at a time, any suggestions?